# Is it safe to create a MetricAffectingSpan that does not implement ParcelableSpan?

Tags: android

I want to create a `MetricAffectingSpan` that does not implement `ParcelableSpan` because its state is not easily persisted without a `Context` instance. Does the framework expect all `MetricAffectingSpan` to implement `ParcelableSpan`? I'm worried that the instance of my class will be cast to `ParcelableSpan` by the Android framework without checking although everything appears to work.

I'm not sure how to provoke the framework into parcelling spans. I've tried to test with `StyleSpan` but never witnessed the constructor that takes a `Parcel` instance being called.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes, it is safe. Parceling is used to communicate state between activities or between processes.

Since custom span information crashes other processes when shared, it might even be a good idea **not** to implement it.

> You can’t create your own ParcelableSpan. To avoid crashes due to unknown data types, the framework doesn’t allow implementing custom ParcelableSpan, by defining two methods, getSpanTypeIdInternal and writeToParcelInternal, as hidden. Both of them are used by TextUtils.writeToParcel.

By Google's own Florina Muntenescu
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/underspanding-spans-1b91008b97e4